# CompletableFuture.runAsync vs array of CompletableFuture

Tags: java, multithreading, completable-future, java-threads

I found this code in a project:

```
int threadCount = 10;
CompletableFuture<?>[] futures = new CompletableFuture<?>[threadCount];
for (int i = 0; i < threadCount; i++) {
    futures[i] = CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> { process.run(queue); });
}
// Wait all futures
CompletableFuture.allOf(futures).join();
```

What's the difference with doing this?

```
ExecutorService threadPool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(threadCount);
CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> { process.run(queue); }, threadPool );
```

Thanks for your explanation.

Comment: Well, your second code snippet both uses a custom `Executor` (whereas the first uses the common `ForkJoinPool`) and doesn't appear to wait for the `CompletableFuture` to complete (it also only launches one task, unlike the first snippet).

Comment: The latter creates one task, which runs on an executor with 10 available threads (i.e. 9 wasted threads, unless you submit more than once in subsequent code), the former creates 10 tasks (usually using a common pool).

Comment: @Michael In `process.run(queue)`, `queue` is a `BlockingQueue` with many elements, so with `CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> { process.run(queue); }, threadPool );` each thread will not call the `process.run(queue)` method?

Comment: No. `#runAsync(Runnable, Executor)` uses the given `Executor` to execute the given `Runnable`. Notice there's only a single `Runnable` which means there's only a single task given to the `Executor`. All the standard implementations of `ExecutorService` use one thread per task.

Comment: @akuma8 `queue` is not related to the executor and the task execution. The number of elements in the queue does not matter.

Comment: @Slaw Thanks for your explanations. So in which case using an ˋExecutor` with many threads is relevant? Since only one thread is used to process the task.

Comment: When you submit more than one task to the thread pool (i.e. `Executor`) then you start to make use of the multiple threads. Your first code snippet does this since it launches 10 tasks, except it uses the [common fork-join pool](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ForkJoinPool.html#commonPool()) which may or may not have 10 threads available (depends on number of cores/system properties and whether or not other tasks are being executed by the pool).

Answer (score 0):

```
int threadCount = 10;
CompletableFuture<?>[] futures = new CompletableFuture<?>[threadCount];
for (int i = 0; i < threadCount; i++) {
    futures[i] = CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> { process.run(queue); });
}
// Wait all futures
CompletableFuture.allOf(futures).join();
```

In this case, you creates set of completable futures which are result of executing asynchronous code in common ForkJoin pool. Then process waits until all futures are completed.

```
ExecutorService threadPool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(threadCount);
CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> { process.run(queue); }, threadPool );
```

In this case, you are executing code in specified thread pool.

The differences between these code blocks

- They are executed in different thread pools (first in common ForkJoin which is default for completable futures, second in specified thread pool)
- In first case you are waiting for set of tasks to be completed, in second - you just running task asynchronously

Comment: Is the 2nd case useless? Since only one thread in the pool will treat the task. I mean all threads will not execute `process.run(queue)` method.

Comment: The only use is that second case runs `process.run(queue)` in other thread (which can be useful in some cases), but the result of `CompletableFuture.runAsync` is ignored, so it does not make sense to do in this way. Same result can be reached without CompletableFuture, i.e. `threadPool.submit(() -> process.run(queue))`.